# JavaScript mudar cor de uma pagina

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Basicamente eu preciso que qnd alguem clique na imagem a pagina mude de cor, estou começando agora no js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcUEn.png)

Answer (score -2):

Depois de inserir a imagem no html e dar um ID a ela, você pode salvar ela em uma variável e adicionar um evento de click nela, com uma callback function. Dentro dessa função você acessa o document.body e altera o style(css) dele para backgroundColor que você quiser

```js
const imagem = document.querySelector('#passaro');
imagem.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
})
```

```html
  <img id="passaro" src="https://www.petz.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/diferenca-entre-aves-e-passaros.jpg" width="400px">
```